# placing pictures from given paths in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some excel files generated from some retail application which include the items and description and some other information, those excel file also include the path of the items images which they're located on the server, I've been searching for a way to let excel places the images from the paths to the same cell where the path is written.

Any help please?

And many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureFileName)` (see [here](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Insert_pictures_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/486.html) for an example program).  You'll probably have to adjust it to fit your needs, but repeated calling of their subroutine in a loop should do the trick.  I'm guessing it's going to run slowly, though.